# How to setup headless firefox browser Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, operating-system, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to setup a headless firefox browser for my Ubuntu Server. I followed instructions on other posts but nothing seems to be working. I get this error when trying to startup firefox.

```
~(branch:master*) » firefox                                                                                                                                                                     jake@ubuntu
Error: no display specified
------------------------------------------------------------
~(branch:master*) » phpunit functional/SiteTest.php                                                                                                                                             jake@ubuntu
------------------------------------------------------------
~(branch:master*) » export DISPLAY=:10                                                                                                                                                          jake@ubuntu
------------------------------------------------------------
~(branch:master*) » firefox                                                                                                                                                                     jake@ubuntu
Error: cannot open display: :10
```

I am thinking it must be something with the display driver.

These are the instructions I am following.

http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Have you verified that `xvfb` is running?

Comment: How would I verify that? I'm not a server adamin I'm a programmer so details would be great.

Comment: you can run `Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &` which will run a virtual desktop on display 10. if it fails you will need to install some packages. You will need some sort of X server running. As your link suggests "Install Xvfb – the X Virtual FrameBuffer"

Comment: Alright thanks I'll try that out and see if that works. Are you running selenium with php unit at all?

Answer (score 1):

Install `xvfb` package:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then run firefox like this:

```
xvfb-run firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1, I installed firefox. This did not work with

```
Couldn't open libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installdfed xvfb

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

and started firefox

```
firefox
```

This worked. Be aware to ssh login with -X

```
ssh -X user@your_headless_box
```

and have something on your host that can display X applications. On Windows that would probably be Xming, on Mac XQuartz